# How to link to an anchor on a webpage?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

How can one reference an [**anchor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_anchor#Anchor) in the (online) Documentation Center? I know how to embed a link for e.g. [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html), but how can one link directly to the `StreamStyle` option under the **Options** section on the same page? Can this anchor-link be extracted from the documentation from under *Mathematica* (like there is the **Copy web URL** functionality at the topright corner of each page)? Apparently this does not work as it simply loads the page without jumping to the bottom:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html#StreamStyle

Comment: Given that the openers are operated using javascript I suppose this may prove to be impossible. Good question, though. I have been looking for this functionality myself before.

Comment: The anchor numbers are the same as the Cell IDs in the documentation. However it seems that you have to pick an element that can be directly selected by clicking on it in order for the resulting anchor to work in the web-based version. So, in this example, the ID for the cell that says "Apply a variety of styles to the streamlines:" (221137153) can be used, but that for the entire cell containing this section (94540846), can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method that I use is to take the anchor from the first example under the option. To do this, click on the `In[1]:=` and copy the shortened URL from the lower right corner of the popup.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice the gray URL in the lower right corner of the popup window.

Comment: I did not know that you can click on `In`/`Out` labels! This method I find more simple to perform than actually checking the source code, therefore I changed my accept.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Note that this "clicking In" to get this link does not work in either chrome or safari (it does work on firefox on my mac), in the sense that you do not get the popup. The links generated this way work nicely in safari and chrome, but strangely in firefox I have to load the page twice in order to jump to the right section. I may not have the latest version of firefox. To view the source of a selection you need an add-on in chrome.

Comment: Ah but (my versions of) chrome and safari seem to be inconvenient for viewing the wolfram documentation in general. I can't open the OpenerViews :(.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I use chrome and it works... It might also depend on your javascript settings.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox these links work:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html#221137153

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html#178218620

the anchor numbers were determined with "View Selection Source" and mk1 eyeball.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard. Could it be that it won't work as expected under other browsers, as there the number's would be different?

Comment: @István as far as I know the number *will not* be different as they are directly out of the page source.  However, I don't know how other browsers handle this situation (in light of Sjoerd's concern) therefore I thought it prudent to mention it.

Comment: I do this all the time and nobody's complained so far. I think I'd probably prefer to take the numbers from the page that's online rather from the documentation if you don't have the latest version of *Mathematica*, though--it's conceivable that the cell IDs might change between versions.

Comment: @Oleksandr it didn't even occur to me to copy the anchors from the documentation Notebooks.  "View Selection Source" is a Firefox browser command.

Comment: I combine the mk1 eyeball with the mk2 search, so I don't have to wade through the hundreds to thousands of lines of html to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: @rcollyer you understand what View *Selection* Source means, right? :-)